# CompileTimeChecker from Modern C++ Design not working as expected

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I've recently started reading Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu. After reading Compile-Time Assertions, I tried the following code:

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker
{
    CompileTimeChecker(...){};
};
template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false>{};

#define STATIC_CHECK(expr, msg) \
{\
    class ERROR_##msg{}; \
    (void)sizeof(CompileTimeChecker<(expr)!=0>((ERROR_##msg())));   /*Line 1*/ }


int main()
{
    STATIC_CHECK(sizeof(char)>sizeof(int),TypeTooNarrow); /*Line 2*/

    STATIC_CHECK(sizeof(char)<sizeof(int),TypeTooNarrow); /*Line 3*/
}
```

The code should not compile due to Line 2, but it compiles fine. If I change the Line 1 to

```
(void)(CompileTimeChecker<(expr)!=0>((ERROR_##msg())));   /*Line 1*/ }
```

or

```
new CompileTimeChecker<(expr)!=0>((ERROR_##msg()));   /* Line 1*/ }
```

it works as expected. I don't get it.

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [CompileTimeChecker from Modern C++ Design not working as expected.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934643/compiletimechecker-from-modern-c-design-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Close the other one as duplicate. Let this one be open.

Comment: @Paul R : I think @Saurabh  posted the same question twice (by mistake I think), the other one has already been closed as a duplicate to this one and now you are closing this considering this one as the dupe of other one.

Comment: @Prasoon: when I voted to close this duplicate both were still open - normally the newer duplicate is closed, but I guess it doesn't matter so long as only one remains

Answer (score 2):

Try [updated version](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/static_check.h?view=markup) from the [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Nikolai: That works. In that code, what's the need for (void)Error_##msg;

Comment: That second statement is there, I'm guessing, so compiler does not complain about unused variable.

Comment: Ok. And do you have anything on the question I actually asked?

Comment: GCC 4.2.1 says this: `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type` about both lines in `main()`, i.e. expanded macro is interpreted as function declaration. That's what the comments in the code I linked to also suggest. Your compiler could be just cheating and skipping the `(void)sizeof(...);` line. Also, the Loki library - all the code from the book and more - wasn't fully compilable by any existing compiler at the time the book was written.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 it's preferable to use `static_assert` rather than this technique. A lot of what is described in *Modern C++ Design* has now been replaced by standard language or library features. It's (probably) still worth reading though.